# How to optimize filtering : Rethink db

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

**introduction**

I have been working with the ReThink Db using data explorer tab. I am new to Rethink Db.

I have created this query to filter record on date base. I needed to optimize the query so that it can take less time for large records.

```
r.db('test').table('usrz').filter(function(test) {
               return test("createdDate").date().during(
                 r.time(2016,12,20, 'Z'),
                 r.time(2016,12,30, 'Z'))
}).orderBy(r.desc('createdDate'))
```

Any help or reference will be apreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RethinkDB queries can be optimized by using indexes. (see https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript)

To create an index:

```
r.table('usrz').indexCreate('createdDate')
```

Your query can be converted to use that index by transforming the `filter`/`during` combination into a `between` and by adding an `index` argument to `orderBy`